# Firebase Notifications Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My main error is this:

> "Argument of #selector refers to instance method 'tokenRefreshNotification' that is not exposed to Objective-C"

This is my AppDelegate:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("appKey")

        FIRApp.configure()

        //Firebase
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions,
                                                                    completionHandler: {_, _ in})

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [ .alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        // Add observer for iNSTANCEid TOKEN REFRESH CALLBACK.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID Token \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token
        connectToFCM()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFCM()
    {
        // Won't connect since there is no token
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
            return
        }

        // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect(completion: {(error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM")
            }
        })

    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]
```

The error line is this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
```

If I add @objc to tokenRefreshNotification I get a new error:

> "Method cannot be marker@objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective C"

Comment: I'm getting this error too - did you fix it yet?

Comment: I am having this problem too. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

the selector is wrong and should be

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(tokenRefreshNotification:), name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
```

There has to be a ":" at the end of the selector.

In addition the method signature seems to be wrong and should be

```
@objc func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: Notification) {
```

The underscore is too much.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue